# How to take this integral: $\int_0^\infty e^{-w^2\cos ^2 x-x} \, dx$?

Tags: integration

How to evaluate

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-w^2\cos ^2 x-x} \, dx$$

I have no clue, indefinite integral also would be a help.

Comment: What is the argument of the cosine?

Comment: You have a cosine with no argument

Comment: @Ron Gordon typo due to a bug in Mathematica! It puts the argument before the function when copying!

Comment: hint: $e^u=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n!}$